# Remove left recursion from grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, left-recursion

Remove left recursion from following grammar :

Q.1

```
S -> SXY | a
X -> xY | xX
Y -> Yy | epsilon
```

Q.2

```
P ->  P H 4 U | p
H -> h
U -> u | u P
```

I know the rules to remove left recursion, but I am confused. So if someone please post the answer of this grammar, it would be helpful.

---

Update from comment:

I know this 2 are left recursive grammar :

```
S -> SXY | a
P -> P H 4 U | p
```

And I know how to remove left recursion from those grammars, but what about other grammars?

```
P -> P ... This is left recursive. 
P -> p ... Is this is also left recursive ?
```

Comment: "I am confused" is not a problem description.  Asking someone to give you the answer is cheating.  SO is a place to get *help*: show us how far you got in the conversion, describe where you're stuck, and we'll get you over the hump.

Comment: I know this 2 are left recursive grammar :
S -> SXY | a     AND 
P ->  P H 4 U | p

And I know how to remove left recursion from that grammars but what about other grammars, Is it left recursive or not ?


P -> P   -> This is left recursive.
P -> p   ->  Is this is also left recursive ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's get the terminology straight: the four lines in your comment (which I added to the question) are grammar *rules*, not grammars.  Each handles only one expansion; none of them provide a path from the start symbol **S** to a string of terminal symbols.

A left-recursive rule is one in which the expansion of the LHS, a non-terminal symbol (capital letter), can result in a longer string that begins with the same symbol.  Thus, **P -> P** is not left-recursive, as the rule is meaningless.  **P -> p** is not left-recursive, as it expands **P**, a non-terminal symbol, to **p** (lower-case), a terminal symbol.

You are correct that the first two rules are left-recursive.

Does that get you moving?  I believe that it answers all of your outstanding specific questions.