# Removing left recursion from JSF*ck grammar rules

Tags: parsing, grammar, recursive-descent

I am trying to figure out a [JSF*uck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) grammar. I read the actual JavaScript grammar [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262) and only took the grammar rules that were relevant to JSF*ck and got this:

```
Expression: AdditiveExpression ;
AdditiveExpression: UnaryExpression             
    | AdditiveExpression '+' UnaryExpression    
    ;
UnaryExpression: UpdateExpression
    | '+' UnaryExpression
    | '!' UnaryExpression
    ;
UpdateExpression: MemberExpression
    | UnaryExpression
    ;
MemberExpression: PrimaryExpression
    | MemberExpression '[' Expression ']'
    ;
PrimaryExpression: ArrayLiteral
    | ParenthesizedExpression
    ;
ParenthesizedExpression: '(' Expression ')' ;
ArrayLiteral: '[' ']' ;
```

Since I'm trying to implement a recursive descent parser, I tried removing left recursion by changing the grammar to this:

```
Expression: AdditiveExpression ;
AdditiveExpression: MemberExpression ('+' AdditiveExpression)? ;
MemberExpression: ('+'|'!') Expression
    | Atom ('[' Expression ']')?
    ; 
Atom: '[' Expression? ']' 
    | '(' Expression ')'
    ;
```

However, my AST doesn't get built correctly. For example, `![]+[]` should be interpreted as `addition(unary_not(array), array)` but I get `unary_not(addition(array, array))` instead. I thought that the unary operators would have a higher precendence since I've defined them further down from the topmost rule compared to addition ?

I've also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69650118/how-to-remove-left-recursion-from-grammar-rules) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760713/remove-left-recursion-from-grammar), but the answers were not really self-explanatory. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What determines what can follow unary `+` or `-` is not so much the order of the productions ("further down from the top") but rather what follows the `(’+'|'-')` in the production. That's `expression`, and `addition(array, array)` is an expression, so that's how it's parsed

You're hoping that even though you wrote `expression`, the parser will restrict it to only certain expressions, but it won't unless you tell it to. So what should you tell it? In this case:

```
MemberExpression: ('+'|'!') MemberExpression
    | Atom ('[' Expression ']')?
```